# How to shrink this cross mesh on this object

Tags: modifiers, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to shrink-wrap this cross object on this complex shape with curves. It shrink-wraps but the result is bad. Is there another method to do this?

I also tried offset, it does shrinkwrap but again the result is incorrect.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will get a better result by

1. using subdivision surface before
2. use project on surface

[image]

but you will have problems in that area:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that Chris, but the result was messy. So the UV mapped worked better in this situation. Cheers.